# Read an external file from a Jar

Tags: java, file-io, fileinputstream

I am using below mentioned code to read a file (`.cer` file) from a java class. The java class will be bundled inside a Jar and then be included into a EAR.

```
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream ("/home/test/foo.cer");
```

I also tried

```
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream ("home/test/foo.cer");
```

But both of them throw FileNotFoundException. The EAR is deployed in Weblogic in a Unix system. I have verified the path and file name.

Any ideas if I have missing anything?

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists in the specified path?

Comment: You need to verify that the file exists , and that the user that runs the Weblogic process has rx access to /home/test to be able to read foo.cer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest including the location of the .cer file on the application server's classpath, and then loading it with ClassLoader's [getResourceAsStream(String location)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method.

If you added the directory `/home/test` to the classpath, appropriate code should be:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("foo.cer");
```

I've found this to be a far more reliable method of loading external resources when running in an appserver, plus it makes testing much easier.

Comment: The existing approach *should* still work, though, unless there's some weird security thing going on.

Comment: Indeed - I'd expect security issues to manifest differently to a FileNotFoundException though - have you seen that before @skaffman?

Comment: Yeah, you generally get `SecurityException`, not `IOException`.

Answer (score -3):

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_NAME_REL_OR_ABSOLUTE));
    reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) { 

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

}
```

Comment: Don't encourage people to write catch blocks like this with no content, especially when dealing with I/O.

Comment: @prunge I was not writing it with no content, i was writing it so that he knows (incase he does not) what 2 IO required exceptions happen during file processing.  What would even be the point of having empty try/catch's?   i would of just done `catch (Exception e) {}` If i was trying to do an empty one....